# Is it possible to use Microsoft Kinect on Intel Galileo board?

Tags: kinect, ros, intel-galileo

I have added the basic ROS to the yocto image on Galileo and tried to compile the `openni_camera` package on it. (drivers like OpenNI were also installed.)

But when I run the command "`rosrun openni_camera openni_node`", the program has no output, nor does it terminate.

Has anyone run `openi_camera` successfully on the Intel Galileo board?

Comment: Hi. Do you have any progress in this area ?

Comment: Not yet, i am thinking to use debian instead of yocto, that will be easier to install ROS, but haven't tried it.