# Kinect driver for Windows Embedded on Intel Galileo

Tags: wifi, driver, kinect, usb-drive, intel-galileo

I would like to know if it's technically possible to write a custom drive for Kinect for Windows v1 or Kinect for Xbox 360, so it could be connected directly to Intel Galileo gen 1 or 2 via USB port with Windows Embedded Pre-Release on the board (avoiding regular PC at all) ?

Related post:
[Is it possible to use Microsoft Kinect on Intel Galileo board?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26792372/is-it-possible-to-use-microsoft-kinect-on-intel-galileo-board)

I am not interested in all data that Kinect provides, but only in depth and maybe in skeleton. In case of depth image there're only 320x240 effective pixels, which are 2 bytes per one with 30FPS, so it's not so huge amount of data. Can Galileo collect it and transfer over Wi-Fi ?

I would like to get some pointing to relevant resources in case if it's possible to do and explanation if it's not.

Thank you